# Implement directive to debouncing multiple inputs

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of inputs and want to apply a filter to a list,
I want to set up debouncing on all inputs.

```
<div class="p-fluid p-grid">

                <div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4 p-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="a" pInputText (input)="loadOpportunities($event)">
                </div>


<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4 p-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="b" pInputText (input)="loadOpportunities($event)">
                </div>

<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4 p-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="c" pInputText (input)="loadOpportunities($event)">
                </div>

<div class="p-field p-col-12 p-md-4 p-lg-2">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="d" pInputText (input)="loadOpportunities($event)">
                </div>
            </div>
```

based on this [article](https://angular.io/guide/http-optimize-server-interaction) how to apply **debounceTime** to all inputs ?

**loadOpportunities** is an httpRequest to send a search request for a filter list to call an API.

Comment: look this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-debounce-directive-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: it works thanks.